# Interface for remote data exchange from Toyota HSR during runtime

Tags: python, communication

I want to pull data, like telemetry, and also push information, like certain commands, onto a Toyota HSR remotely during runtime of the robot.

I could only find this Figure just showing a web-based UI and a Python Interface:[image: https://doi.org/10.1186/s40648-019-0132-3]
https://doi.org/10.1186/s40648-019-0132-3

Is there no OPC-UA support for the Toyota HSR, or is this Python Interface also accessible remotely?

I also don't just want to strap a Laptop on the back of it like these researches did:[image: http://dx.doi.org/10.15622/ia.20.6.1]
http://dx.doi.org/10.15622/ia.20.6.1

Comment: please edit your question... add links to the sources of the two images

Comment: Sorry I only put it in the image description which I didn't realize doesn't show in the question